# Download JSON data into Android App

Tags: java, android, json

I am building an application, which will download JSON data from a url and display it in an android application. Something which im fairly new to.

I am having trouble with downloading the json data, can please somebody help?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ListView EmployeesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.EmployeesList);




    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        // the url we wish to connect to
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/");
        // open the connection to the specified URL
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // get the response from the server in an input stream
        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // covert the input stream to a string
    String response = convertStreamToString(in);
    // print the response to android monitor/log cat
    System.out.println("Server response = " + response);

}


public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

}

Comment: What trouble/error? What code do you use? We can't guess.

Comment: what do you mean by download, do you mean consume a webservice?

Comment: @Mehdi i have already created the web servce, i want to use android studio to download the data from a url

Comment: @sudo i dont have any code, i dont know how to implement this.

Comment: @GRattab StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: This is a full example about parsing data with Json, it might help:                       http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do the thing which you want. My suggestion is to use volley (as one of the best, modern and fairly good) libraries to perform JSON parsing.

[Here is short example which will provide to you an idea how to do this.](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Note that this is only an idea how you can perform actions to achieve your goal!

Also, you can do those actions over POJO's, HTTP request handling, other libraries .... There is a lot of different ways. Google it and choose what is best fit for you.

Comment: Is there not a way without PJO